# What is com.sun.proxy.$Proxy

Tags: java, jpa, proxy, jvm

I have seen that when errors occur deep in different frameworks (e.g frameworks implementing the EJB specification or some JPA providers) the stacktrace contain classes like `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy`. I know what a Proxy is, but I am looking for a more technical and more java specific answer.

1. What are they?
2. How are they created?
3. What is there relationship to the JVM? Are they JVM implementation specific?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. Proxies are classes that are created and loaded at runtime. There is no source code for these classes. I know that you are wondering how you can make them do something if there is no code for them. The answer is that when you create them, you specify an object that implements `InvocationHandler`, which defines a method that is invoked when a proxy method is invoked.
2. You create them by using the call

   ```
   Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, interfaces, invocationHandler)
   ```

   The arguments are:

   1. `classLoader`. Once the class is generated, it is loaded with this class loader.
   2. `interfaces`. An array of class objects that must all be interfaces. The resulting proxy implements all of these interfaces.
   3. `invocationHandler`. This is how your proxy knows what to do when a method is invoked. It is an object that implements `InvocationHandler`. When a method from any of the supported interfaces, or `hashCode`, `equals`, or `toString`, is invoked, the method `invoke` is invoked on the handler, passing the `Method` object for the method to be invoked and the arguments passed.

   For more on this, see the documentation for the [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class.
3. Every implementation of a JVM after version 1.3 must support these. They are loaded into the internal data structures of the JVM in an implementation-specific way, but it is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 55):

## What are they?

Nothing special. Just as same as common Java Class Instance.

But those class are `Synthetic proxy classes` created by [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy#newProxyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class[],%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler))

## What is there relationship to the JVM? Are they JVM implementation specific?

Introduced in 1.3

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/relnotes/features.html#reflection

It is a part of Java. so each JVM should support it.

## How are they created (Openjdk7 source)?

In short : they are created using JVM ASM tech ( defining javabyte code at runtime  )

something using same tech:

- asm( http://asm.ow2.org/ )
- cglib( http://cglib.sourceforge.net/ )

### What happens after calling `java.lang.reflect.Proxy#newProxyInstance`

1. reading the source you can see newProxyInstance call `getProxyClass0` to obtain a `Class

   `
2. after lots of cache or sth it calls the magic `ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass` which return a byte[]
3. call ClassLoader `define class` to load the generated `$Proxy` Class (the classname you have seen)
4. just instance it and ready for use

### What happens in magic sun.misc.ProxyGenerator

1. draw a class(bytecode) combining all methods in the interfaces into one
2. each method is build with same bytecode like

   1. get calling Method meth info (stored while generating)
   2. pass info into `invocation handler`'s `invoke()`
   3. get return value from `invocation handler`'s `invoke()`
   4. just return it
3. the class(bytecode) represent in form of `byte[]`

**How to draw a class**

Thinking your java codes are compiled into bytecodes, just do this at runtime

## Talk is cheap show you the code

core method in sun/misc/ProxyGenerator.java

generateClassFile

```
/**
 * Generate a class file for the proxy class.  This method drives the
 * class file generation process.
 */
private byte[] generateClassFile() {

    /* ============================================================
     * Step 1: Assemble ProxyMethod objects for all methods to
     * generate proxy dispatching code for.
     */

    /*
     * Record that proxy methods are needed for the hashCode, equals,
     * and toString methods of java.lang.Object.  This is done before
     * the methods from the proxy interfaces so that the methods from
     * java.lang.Object take precedence over duplicate methods in the
     * proxy interfaces.
     */
    addProxyMethod(hashCodeMethod, Object.class);
    addProxyMethod(equalsMethod, Object.class);
    addProxyMethod(toStringMethod, Object.class);

    /*
     * Now record all of the methods from the proxy interfaces, giving
     * earlier interfaces precedence over later ones with duplicate
     * methods.
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++) {
        Method[] methods = interfaces[i].getMethods();
        for (int j = 0; j < methods.length; j++) {
            addProxyMethod(methods[j], interfaces[i]);
        }
    }

    /*
     * For each set of proxy methods with the same signature,
     * verify that the methods' return types are compatible.
     */
    for (List<ProxyMethod> sigmethods : proxyMethods.values()) {
        checkReturnTypes(sigmethods);
    }

    /* ============================================================
     * Step 2: Assemble FieldInfo and MethodInfo structs for all of
     * fields and methods in the class we are generating.
     */
    try {
        methods.add(generateConstructor());

        for (List<ProxyMethod> sigmethods : proxyMethods.values()) {
            for (ProxyMethod pm : sigmethods) {

                // add static field for method's Method object
                fields.add(new FieldInfo(pm.methodFieldName,
                    "Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;",
                     ACC_PRIVATE | ACC_STATIC));

                // generate code for proxy method and add it
                methods.add(pm.generateMethod());
            }
        }

        methods.add(generateStaticInitializer());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new InternalError("unexpected I/O Exception");
    }

    if (methods.size() > 65535) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("method limit exceeded");
    }
    if (fields.size() > 65535) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("field limit exceeded");
    }

    /* ============================================================
     * Step 3: Write the final class file.
     */

    /*
     * Make sure that constant pool indexes are reserved for the
     * following items before starting to write the final class file.
     */
    cp.getClass(dotToSlash(className));
    cp.getClass(superclassName);
    for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++) {
        cp.getClass(dotToSlash(interfaces[i].getName()));
    }

    /*
     * Disallow new constant pool additions beyond this point, since
     * we are about to write the final constant pool table.
     */
    cp.setReadOnly();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(bout);

    try {
        /*
         * Write all the items of the "ClassFile" structure.
         * See JVMS section 4.1.
         */
                                    // u4 magic;
        dout.writeInt(0xCAFEBABE);
                                    // u2 minor_version;
        dout.writeShort(CLASSFILE_MINOR_VERSION);
                                    // u2 major_version;
        dout.writeShort(CLASSFILE_MAJOR_VERSION);

        cp.write(dout);             // (write constant pool)

                                    // u2 access_flags;
        dout.writeShort(ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_FINAL | ACC_SUPER);
                                    // u2 this_class;
        dout.writeShort(cp.getClass(dotToSlash(className)));
                                    // u2 super_class;
        dout.writeShort(cp.getClass(superclassName));

                                    // u2 interfaces_count;
        dout.writeShort(interfaces.length);
                                    // u2 interfaces[interfaces_count];
        for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.length; i++) {
            dout.writeShort(cp.getClass(
                dotToSlash(interfaces[i].getName())));
        }

                                    // u2 fields_count;
        dout.writeShort(fields.size());
                                    // field_info fields[fields_count];
        for (FieldInfo f : fields) {
            f.write(dout);
        }

                                    // u2 methods_count;
        dout.writeShort(methods.size());
                                    // method_info methods[methods_count];
        for (MethodInfo m : methods) {
            m.write(dout);
        }

                                     // u2 attributes_count;
        dout.writeShort(0); // (no ClassFile attributes for proxy classes)

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new InternalError("unexpected I/O Exception");
    }

    return bout.toByteArray();
}
```

addProxyMethod

```
/**
 * Add another method to be proxied, either by creating a new
 * ProxyMethod object or augmenting an old one for a duplicate
 * method.
 *
 * "fromClass" indicates the proxy interface that the method was
 * found through, which may be different from (a subinterface of)
 * the method's "declaring class".  Note that the first Method
 * object passed for a given name and descriptor identifies the
 * Method object (and thus the declaring class) that will be
 * passed to the invocation handler's "invoke" method for a given
 * set of duplicate methods.
 */
private void addProxyMethod(Method m, Class fromClass) {
    String name = m.getName();
    Class[] parameterTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
    Class returnType = m.getReturnType();
    Class[] exceptionTypes = m.getExceptionTypes();

    String sig = name + getParameterDescriptors(parameterTypes);
    List<ProxyMethod> sigmethods = proxyMethods.get(sig);
    if (sigmethods != null) {
        for (ProxyMethod pm : sigmethods) {
            if (returnType == pm.returnType) {
                /*
                 * Found a match: reduce exception types to the
                 * greatest set of exceptions that can thrown
                 * compatibly with the throws clauses of both
                 * overridden methods.
                 */
                List<Class<?>> legalExceptions = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
                collectCompatibleTypes(
                    exceptionTypes, pm.exceptionTypes, legalExceptions);
                collectCompatibleTypes(
                    pm.exceptionTypes, exceptionTypes, legalExceptions);
                pm.exceptionTypes = new Class[legalExceptions.size()];
                pm.exceptionTypes =
                    legalExceptions.toArray(pm.exceptionTypes);
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        sigmethods = new ArrayList<ProxyMethod>(3);
        proxyMethods.put(sig, sigmethods);
    }
    sigmethods.add(new ProxyMethod(name, parameterTypes, returnType,
                                   exceptionTypes, fromClass));
}
```

Full code about gen the proxy method

```
    private MethodInfo generateMethod() throws IOException {
        String desc = getMethodDescriptor(parameterTypes, returnType);
        MethodInfo minfo = new MethodInfo(methodName, desc,
            ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_FINAL);

        int[] parameterSlot = new int[parameterTypes.length];
        int nextSlot = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterSlot.length; i++) {
            parameterSlot[i] = nextSlot;
            nextSlot += getWordsPerType(parameterTypes[i]);
        }
        int localSlot0 = nextSlot;
        short pc, tryBegin = 0, tryEnd;

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(minfo.code);

        code_aload(0, out);

        out.writeByte(opc_getfield);
        out.writeShort(cp.getFieldRef(
            superclassName,
            handlerFieldName, "Ljava/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler;"));

        code_aload(0, out);

        out.writeByte(opc_getstatic);
        out.writeShort(cp.getFieldRef(
            dotToSlash(className),
            methodFieldName, "Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;"));

        if (parameterTypes.length > 0) {

            code_ipush(parameterTypes.length, out);

            out.writeByte(opc_anewarray);
            out.writeShort(cp.getClass("java/lang/Object"));

            for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {

                out.writeByte(opc_dup);

                code_ipush(i, out);

                codeWrapArgument(parameterTypes[i], parameterSlot[i], out);

                out.writeByte(opc_aastore);
            }
        } else {

            out.writeByte(opc_aconst_null);
        }

        out.writeByte(opc_invokeinterface);
        out.writeShort(cp.getInterfaceMethodRef(
            "java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler",
            "invoke",
            "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;" +
                "[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;"));
        out.writeByte(4);
        out.writeByte(0);

        if (returnType == void.class) {

            out.writeByte(opc_pop);

            out.writeByte(opc_return);

        } else {

            codeUnwrapReturnValue(returnType, out);
        }

        tryEnd = pc = (short) minfo.code.size();

        List<Class<?>> catchList = computeUniqueCatchList(exceptionTypes);
        if (catchList.size() > 0) {

            for (Class<?> ex : catchList) {
                minfo.exceptionTable.add(new ExceptionTableEntry(
                    tryBegin, tryEnd, pc,
                    cp.getClass(dotToSlash(ex.getName()))));
            }

            out.writeByte(opc_athrow);

            pc = (short) minfo.code.size();

            minfo.exceptionTable.add(new ExceptionTableEntry(
                tryBegin, tryEnd, pc, cp.getClass("java/lang/Throwable")));

            code_astore(localSlot0, out);

            out.writeByte(opc_new);
            out.writeShort(cp.getClass(
                "java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException"));

            out.writeByte(opc_dup);

            code_aload(localSlot0, out);

            out.writeByte(opc_invokespecial);

            out.writeShort(cp.getMethodRef(
                "java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException",
                "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V"));

            out.writeByte(opc_athrow);
        }
```