# At what point is a transaction commited?

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, entity

I've read  about [entities lifecycle](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_emfactory_perscontext.html), and [the locking strategies](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html), and I watched some videos about this but I'm still not sure I understand.I understand there is also a locking mechanism in the underlying RDBMS (I'm using mysql).

I would like to know at what point a transaction is committed / entity is detached and how does it affect other transactions from a locking point of view. At what point does an user have to wait till a transaction finishes ? I've made two different scenarios below. For the sake of understanding I'm asserting the table in the scenarios contains a lot of rows and the `for` loops takes 10 minute to complete.

**Scenario 1:**

```
@Stateless
public class AService implements AServiceInterface {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-pu")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Override
    public List<Aclass> getAll() {
        Query query = em.createQuery(SELECT_ALL_ROWS);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
    public void update(Aclass a) {
        em.merge(a);     
    }
}
```

*and a calling class:*

```
public aRadomClass{
    @EJB
    AServiceInterface service;

    public void method(){
       List<Aclass> listAclass = service.getAll();
       for(Aclass a : listAclass){
           a.setProperty(methodThatTakesTime());
           service.update(a); 
       }
    }
}
```

Without specifying a locking strategy : If another user wants to makes an update to *one* row in the table and the for loop already began but is not finished. Does he have to wait till the `for` loop is completed ?

**Scenario 2:**

```
@Stateless
public class AService implements AServiceInterface {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-pu")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Aclass> getAllAndUpdate() {
        Query query = em.createQuery(SELECT_ALL_ROWS);
        List<Aclass> listAclass = query.getResultList();
        for(Aclass a : listAclass ){
           a.setProperty(methodThatTakesTime());
           em.merge(a);
        }    
    }
}
```

Same question.

Comment: Read about [concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important what kind of class is your aRandomClass. If it is also an EJB, you should take a look in the [transaction propagation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html). If it is a servlet, then the transaction is closed automatically right after your EJB method exits (no matter which one). That is done using [dynamic proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633534/what-is-com-sun-proxy-proxy). So in scenario 1 the EJB container will open and close multiple transactions: one for `service.getAll()` and one for each `service.update(a)` call. In scenario 2, if method `getAllAndUpdate()` is called only once, a single transaction will be opened and it will be closed on method exit.

Comment: @AndreiL You say it's important if it's an EJB, not the case for a managedBean right ? So in scenario 1, if the for loop is on going and someone makes an update to a row, is it possible then that the update is done while the loop is ongoing but in scenario 2 he has to wait ? Like I'm imagining the for loop begins, makes a transaction, close it, then before opening another transaction to finish the loop, the update transaction from another user takes place then the loop goes on ?

Comment: About managed beans I am not sure, but it is very easy to test: [enable all queries executed by MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) and then start to debug you application and check on which step what is done.

Comment: I don't really get your question in your comment. If you are in that loop in scenario 1, every time you are done with a for-cycle, the transaction is closed and any held DB locks will be lost on closing the transaction (but in your code you do not hold any locks anyway, except you use the serializable [transaction isolation mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) ).