# List size should be 2 but its giving 3 why?

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting size of list as 3,even if I remove a element from the list when I am using **@FindBy** annotation.

When I execute my code without @FindBy annotation I am getting correct list size as 2.

**List has following elements:[Instructor,course,price]**

Please help me why I am getting this two behavior?

```
public class TestClass {

static WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(xpath = "//th")
public List<WebElement> columns;

List<WebElement> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();

public void initMethod() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public List<WebElement> getColumns() {
    // output of below line = Initial columns list size 3
    System.out.println("Initial columns list size " + columns.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(columns.get(i).getText());
        if (columns.get(i).getText().equals("Instructor"))
            columns.remove(i);
    }
    // output of below line = After modification column list size 3
    System.out.println("After modification column list size " + columns.size());
    return columns;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F://chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.qaclickacademy.com/practice.php");
    TestClass test = new TestClass();
    test.initMethod();
    test.getColumns();
}
}
```

Comment: Which kind of List does Selenium inject? Could be that it is an immutable list and you need to re-assign it.

Comment: @LppEdd,I guess Selenium injects mutable list not sure

Comment: Debug it and see. It's the only cause if you're sure the elements are correct.

Comment: @LppEdd,even official document doesn't mention anything as such about immutability of list

Comment: Debug it. It's the only real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium use lazy proxy for init WebElement and List fields in PageFactory.
Selenium locate elements each time you use `columns` and because there are 3 `th` elements on the page `columns` get back all 3 items.
@FindBy basically replaces `driver.findElements()`:

```
// Here columns locating again on the page
System.out.println("Initial columns list size " + columns.size());
// It works same as code below
System.out.println("Initial columns list size " + driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th")).size());

// All places you use columns, columns locating elements again, and you code is same as here.
for (int i = 0; i < driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th")).size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th")).get(i).getText());
    if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th")).get(i).getText().equals("Instructor"))
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th")).remove(i);
}
// output of below line = After modification column list size 3
System.out.println("After modification column list size " + driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th")).size());
return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th"));
```

About `PageFactory` you can find information [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) and about `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633534/what-is-com-sun-proxy-proxy).

To remove item from the `columns`, you can use one of methods below:

```
List<WebElement> columns1 = this.columns.stream()
        .filter(e -> !e.getText().equals("Instructor"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<WebElement> columns2 = new ArrayList<>();
columns.forEach(column -> {
    if (!column.getText().equals("Instructor"))
        columns2.add(column);
});
```

Your method can be:

```
public List<WebElement> getColumns() {
    return columns.stream()
            .filter(e -> !e.getText().equals("Instructor"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: can't my same list give modified list.I can see here in both examples you provided has used different list..please clarify?

Comment: @BlueStar I try to explain why you get back 3 items even you delete one and you can't modify your list

Comment: ,so only real solution to this is to create another list and use the newly created list to get the modified result because if we use the same list again it will again locate all columns.Please reply Thanks.

Comment: @BlueStar you exclude Instructor from xpath

Comment: ,Then How will I remove that element,if I exclude it?My task is to remove the element if its equal to "Instructor" only,and I might dont have the instructor in some cases so I have used it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply will try to implement this

Comment: @BlueStar you can use `//th[not(.='Instructor')]` xpath