# Proxy Error - at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.run(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

My Spring Batch job failed but I am not sure what is wrong with it. There is not any valid code which I wrote is shown in the Exception. Below is what I got in the logs:

```
2021-12-28 10:39:35.062 ERROR 30652 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step masterStep in job importUserJob

org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:112)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:772)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at alfresco.bulkimport.folders.Application.main(Application.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

My Spring Boot App Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); 
        
    }
}
```

My Spring Batch Job Config:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Value("file:input/*.txt")
    private Resource[] inputResources;

    @Autowired
    private FlatFileItemReader<FolderNodePojo> nodeItemReader;

    @Bean("partitioner")
    @StepScope
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        log.info("In Partitioner");

        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        partitioner.setResources(inputResources);
        partitioner.partition(10);
        return partitioner;
    }

    @Bean
    public NodeItemProcessor processor() {
        return new NodeItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public NodeItemWriter<FolderNodePojo> writer() {
        return new NodeItemWriter<FolderNodePojo>();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobFinishListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .flow(masterStep()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<FolderNodePojo, FolderNodePojo>chunk(5).reader(nodeItemReader)
                .processor(processor()).writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Thread");
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("masterStep")
    public Step masterStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep").partitioner("step1", partitioner()).step(step1())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @Qualifier("nodeItemReader")
    @DependsOn("partitioner")
    public FlatFileItemReader<FolderNodePojo> NodeItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<FolderNodePojo>().name("NodeItemReader").delimited().delimiter("<#|FooBar|#>")
                .names(new String[] { "id" }).fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<FolderNodePojo>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(FolderNodePojo.class);
                    }
                }).linesToSkip(0).resource(new UrlResource(filename)).build();
    }

}
```

I tried to follow this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633534/what-is-com-sun-proxy-proxy) and some similar threads but could not relate them to my situation. My situation is while using Spring Batch/Job/Step. Any idea/clue will be greatly appreciated. I am clueless and not sure where to start debugging. Kindly let me know if any other details/aspects are required to look into. I can provide.