# Modifying HTTP response body and message

Tags: java, jax-rs

I need to be able to modify the HTTP response body of the response that I am getting when someone hits my Service API. I tried using ConatinerResponseFilter to modify the body, but I believe it will only modify the headers and not the response body. Can someone tell me how I can modify the HTTP response body ,message and the status?

Comment: `response.data` will have your response body `console.log(response);` to see what your API is returning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be achieved with a [`WriterInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html):

```java
@Provider
public class CustomWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) 
                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();

        // Manipulate the HTTP entity using the OutputStream

        context.setOutputStream(outputStream);
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36546268/1426227) you will find an example of how to modify a JSON sent in the *request payload* using Jackson (the same idea can be used to manipulate *response payload*).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a wrapper because body when read as a stream becomes in accessible

[Modify HttpServletRequest body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681263/modify-httpservletrequest-body)

Check this or just check online for modify body in filter

Note :if u are doing a web service then using frameworks like CXF makes it easy modify

Comment: The OP wants to modify the *response payload*.